# Issue when redirecting a folder using IIS url rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Using Url Rewrite, I'm trying to redirect /foo_bar/* to /foo/*. I've tried this:

```
<rule name="Redirect foo_bar to foo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^/foo_bar/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/foo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But this just redirects to /foo/foo_bar/*. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the match.  I don't think you even need a condition for that.  Just try the following:

```
<rule name="Redirect foo_bar to foo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*/foo_bar/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/foo/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Any idea why I can't match in the manner I tried?

Comment: The problem is the splitting of the url happens in the match and not in the condition.  when you split on the whole URL the {R:1} variable will have the entire url.  You might want to try using the gui for URL rewrite.  You can test the input...